# How to make particles refract/change direction through an object

Tags: objects, particles

As the title states above, I want a line of particles that is produced from an emitter to go in an object and change direction, like a refracting effect.

Any and all ideas will help. I know that these particles will be not be effected by gravity, but can be effected by other forces.

Here is a picture to better explain my point.[image]

Comment: also know that this will be for an animation

Answer (score 1):

you need to use keyed physics in particle system,then use a curve of your desired shape as the guide for leading the particles,here's how you do;

1. create a particle system,crank up the lifetime and play around with
   emitter geometry.
2. Create a curve of desired shape.
3. Create another particle system at the end of the curve.
4. In physics tab,select Newtonian,then add keys and select the target.

Voila there you go.

Comment: i am having trouble with step 4. do i select newtonian then keyed? and target would the curve right?

Comment: sorry i added Newtonian by mistake,select keyed.you could use the curve as well but you have to convert it to mesh and apply particle system before you can use it as target.This is a time consuming task as well as you have to do a lot of manual tweaking with emitter geometry.Instead select the next emitter object at the end of curve as target.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is set up two circles as emitters, one outside the object and the other inside it on the other end.

Then key the first particle stream to the second.  So, set #1 from frames 1 to 50, key the first stream, then hit the plus sign and add the second by clicking on the little box and pulling the name up from the list.

Set the second particle stream emitter from frames to 60 to 110.
[image][image]